# Changing data type in python from complex to int

Tags: python, types

## # Is it possible to change a complex number to int.

a= 4+3i
b = int(a)
print(b)

### Is there any other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A complex number cannot be represented as an integer.

You can retrieve the real and the imag parts respectively like:

```
a = 4+3j

print(a.real)  # 4.0 as float
print(a.imag)  # 3.0 as float
```

Also you can retrieve the absolute value of the number using the `abs` function:

```py
print(abs(a))  # 5.0 as float
```

Then you can convert the float numbers to integer, but that way you might lose the precision of the representation which is might not what you want.